# CSS/jQuery drop down menu content appearing outside of area after hover over

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to website design/javascript/css so I really have my work cut out!

[This](http://www.silx.netii.net/) is what I have so far, the problem I have is when you hover over the activities tab and move between the elements, the page navigation bar spills out the content under the bar. the code I have (sorry if I forget something) is as follows:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu > li:has(ul)").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).children("ul").css("display", "none");
            $(this).children("ul").css("left", "auto").fadeIn('slow');
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).children("ul").delay(300).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).children("ul").css("left", "-9999em");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $("ul#menu > li").fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
    $("ul#menu > li").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
            }
    );
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li.group").hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).find('ul:first').stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
                });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar
{
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #0F0F0F;
    alignment-adjust: auto;
}
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: 0F0F0F;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background: #1C1C1C;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index:99;height:auto;
  height:50px;
}
li:hover a {
    background: #0F0F0F;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1C1C1C;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="inthemix.html">In The Mix</a></li>
            <li><a href="teenbar.html">Teen Bar</a></li>
            <li><a href="outings.html">Outings and trips</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your css file and reduce the height

```
li:hover li{height:26px;}
```

**Edit**

```
ul.menu li ul{position:absolute;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll give that a try and post back with the results.

Comment: Ok, this formatted the drop down content better. I still have the same problem though. The hover over animation seems to be the problem (though with my inexperience i cannot be sure of this.),  when the fade effect starts. when it has been triggered multiple times it causes the contents of the drop down to be displayed under the navigation bar (i.e. if you hover over the drop down, then move to the next element and back repeatedly). Hope this is more clear!

Comment: Added your code to my CSS, still no change. Thank you for your help though!